# Can't use external monitor with Ubuntu 12.04, Fn+F5 doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, screen, external-monitor, eeepc

Hi I have an Asus eeepc 901 and now I installed Lubuntu 12.04 on it. Everything works fine except I can't use external Monitors.

If I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> which used to be the right keys for eeebuntu (the previous distro) nothing happens, the monitor doesn't get a signal.

What can I do?

Comment: Just to let you know, Ubuntu 12.04 multi monitor support is absolutely rubbish.  At best I was able to get 4 monitors working using xinerama, but with xinerama enabled, I lose the ability to use Unity3D and with Unity2D, it has some bug with the default theme...  So in all, it's a bit of a disaster.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at the `System Tools`, `Preferences`, and `Sound and Video` selections for a control panel useful for turning on the second monitor. The function key may have changed, or been eliminated, in Lubuntu from EEbuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question without knowing more information.

Would you please type command `xrandr` in a terminal. Post the output in your question by using the edit function.

Answer (score 0):

Install the gui xrandr interface, arandr, via synaptic or (sudo apt-get install arandr).

Here's an arandr tutorial which allows you to map the external monitor to hotkeys in Lubuntu:
http://lubuntutips.blogspot.com/2012/05/dual-monitors-in-lubuntu.html